# Is making my eye color lighter prohibited?

Tags: quran

Regardless of the way, is it prohibited if I just make it lighter like not making it green or blue or anything?

Comment: Unecessarily messing with Allah's creation. Is there any medical reason?

Comment: No but I just want to know

Comment: Same as: [Changing eye color by lessening the amount of melanin in eyes and not by surgery](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46418/17163)

Answer (score 0):

Say your eyes color is **brown**.

> Dark Brown — Brown — Light Brown

are three different colors as they have different levels of intensity (shades) of the original color (brown).

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_brown) in Wikipedia, they stated:

> Brown color names are often not very precise, and some shades, such as beige, can refer to a wide variety of **colors**, including shades of yellow or red.

They consider the shades of the same color to be different colors.

So, if you were to change the intensity of your eyes color to a lighter one, for example, it would be prohibited (Haram) in Islam as it is considered a different color (light brown) even if it hasn't been standardized by a name yet.

According to the same article:

> There are no standardized names for shades of brown; the same shade may have different names on different color lists...

Answer (score 0):

If you get a surgery to permanently change the color of your eyes, that is prohibited as you have changed the creation of Allah.
As for colored contact lenses:
these come under the rulings on adornment. If a woman wears them for her husband, there is nothing wrong with it. If she is wearing them where others will see her too, then it should not cause any fitnah or temptation. There is also the condition that they should not cause any harm, and there should be no element of cheating or deceiving, such as a woman wearing them when she meets the man who is proposing marriage to her. Also, they should not be extravagantly expensive, because Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning): “… and waste not by extravagance…” [al-An’aam 6:141].
But the main preoccupation of men and youth should not be adornment and beautification. The Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) forbade going to extremes in that. Abu Dawood (4160) narrated that the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) forbade us to be overly concerned with our outward appearance. Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Sunan Abi Dawood.
So if you are man, it is permissible but the above applies.
Also, they should resemble the eyes of a donkey or a dog
Because of the following:
“So his parable is the parable of a dog: if you drive him away, he lolls his tongue out, or if you leave him alone, he (still) lolls his tongue out”

[al-A ‘raaf 7:176]

“The likeness of those who were entrusted with the (obligation of the) Tawraat (Torah) (i.e. to obey its commandments and to practise its laws), but who subsequently failed in those (obligations), is as the likeness of a donkey which carries huge burdens of books (but understands nothing from them)”

[al-Jumu ‘ah 62:5].

And as in the words of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) concerning the one who takes back his gift: “[he is] like the dog that vomits then goes back to its vomit.”

Answer (score 0):

You cannot permanently change it as that is changing the creation of Allah. You can however, wear contact lenses of a lighter color, that is permissible.
And Allah Knows Best

Answer (score -2):

There is a famous hadith:

> “What is allowed is that which God has permitted in his book, and what
> is prohibited is that which God has forbidden in his book, and what he has
> remained silent about is forgivable.”
>
> Al-Tirmidhi, 1726. Classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.

There exist no verses or authentic hadiths which prohibits women from changing their eye colour.

Therefore, It is not prohibited.

Comment: The hadith says it's *forgiveable*, not that it's *permissible*.  (And aren't all sins forgiveable?)  I feel like we need to dig deeper to understand how this hadith applies in particular cases.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones . Do you have a reference for that? Because a version I found in Sunan Ibn Majah says 'halal/permissable' too: https://sunnah.com/urn/1274750

Comment: @TheZ I mean the one in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. But is it considered changing in god's creation?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Ibn Majah uses the term "pardoned" which further reiterates the argument, implying it has be"forgiven in advance" I know a little bit of Arabic. The terms used in this hadith are "فھو مما عفا غنہ" which means "He forgave him" more like the second form of "forgive". This hadith is present in a book named "Sahih wazaif Suna al-Tirmidhi" by Al-Albaani. The book classifies this hadith as authentic. Therefore, I hope there is no need to dive deeper into this any further. Remember the cow of bani israel? They tried going deeper & ended up making alot of problems for themselves

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I was also able to find an online direct reference from Tirmidhi [here](https://muflihun.com/tirmidhi/22/1726)

Comment: @useruyuy Off course, it is changing Allah's creation. Why do you ask?

Comment: @TheZ it is also in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/24/7).

Comment: Why assume this question is about women?

Answer (score -2):

1 man killed 100 and got forgiven that’s nothing for Allah even shirk gets forgiven if you’re alive when you do it and don’t die with it Allah is the king of all kings the boss of all bosses the one who says be and it happens Allah knows we do mistakes that’s why his forgiveness door is open until you die and yet when you’re resurrected he still forgives you.